# Why ferromagnetism requires exactly 2 electrons in the last orbit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, atoms

All magnetic materials like iron, cobalt etc.. have 2 electrons at the last orbit. But magnetic field occurs even if a single charge moves. Why exactly 2?

Comment: Just a side note that, interestingly, the best conductivity happpens with exactly one electron on the top suborbit, but not an s-electron (silver, copper, and gold).

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is true that classical magnetic fields can be created by currents, i.e. moving charges, the observed fenomenon of ferromagnetism is not explained by such a scheme, and in fact it can only be explained by quantum mechanical effects.

Now, it is true that the valence shell of iron has 2 electrons, namely $4s^2$, but the magnetic effect does not come from them, since they completely fill $s$ orbital, and by the pauli exclusion principle they have to be in a state of total magnetic moment equal to 0. Ferromagnetism in iron, and all the other substances that present it, is actually explained by the unpaired electrons in the higher energy orbits.

For iron we have the higher energy, last occupied orbit, $3d$, with $6$ electrons, being two of them paired, with total magnetic moment equal to $0$, and $3$ unpaired electrons, that have their spins aligned giving rise to a net magnetic moment. In a bar magnet the macroscopic magnetic field is the net effect of summing up the tiny magnetic moments of the electrons of each individual atom.